# xcode 6 storing variable into NSdictionary

Tags: arrays, xcode, nsdictionary, storage

I would like to check how do I add an int variable into NSDictionary and display it on table view. From what i research on net it only shows how to add string into nsdictionary but not variable. Appreciate everybody's help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Code! To add an element you've gotta use NSMutableDictionary and not NSDictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dict setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 2]];
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks for the help bro but I'm using objective C instead and I'm new to Xcode so I don really understand swift language

Comment: Well I just edited the answer for Obj-C. Please Up-Vote and Tick it if it helped you!